# how to draw a little crown above a math symbol

Tags: accents

I'd like to have a command `\crown` that would draw a little crown above a symbol, e.g. `$\crown x$` should show an `$x$` with a little crown over it.  I know I can use the `accents` package to declare any symbol as an accent, but how do I create a compatible symbol?

Comment: `stackengine` package, perhaps? Which package provides a crown at all?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go out to the web and find a crown image that suits, such as http://images.clipartpanda.com/queen-crown-clipart-black-and-white-black-crown-clipart-nTE8GkyTA.gif.  If it is not the proper format (this is a gif), use your graphics software (e.g., MSPaint) to save it as a jpeg.

**MATH MODE version**

Then, just patch its name into the `\crownset` macro definition below, adjusting the leading `\kern` if the image had asymmetric horizontal space about it.  Other parameters that can be tweaked include the overset gap, currently set to `.7pt`, and image width, currently set to `1.2\LMex`.

The stack is set up to ignore the width of the crown during the typeset, so that `\crownset is` does not adversely affect the horizontal spacing.

EDITED to account for slant of math font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx,scalerel}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}
\newcommand\crownset[1]{\ensurestackMath{\ThisStyle{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{$\ThisStyle#1$}%
  \stackengine{.7pt}{\SavedStyle#1}{\kern\dimexpr-.1\LMex+.25\ht0\relax%
  \includegraphics[width=1.2\LMex]%
  {queen-crown-clipart-black-and-white-black-crown-clipart-nTE8GkyTA}}%
  {O}{c}{F}{T}{S}}}}
\begin{document}
\[
y = m \crownset x + \frac{\crownset{f}}{\crownset y^2}
\]
\[
\scriptstyle y = m \crownset x + \frac{\crownset{f}}{\crownset y^2}
\]
\[
\scriptscriptstyle y = m \crownset x + \frac{\crownset{f}}{\crownset y^2}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If I don't like that crown, just find another, such as https://openclipart.org/image/2400px/svg_to_png/242116/Royal-Crown-Silhouette.png and substitute the file name into the macro:

[image]

**TEXT MODE version**

The stack is set up to ignore the width of the crown during the typeset, so that `\crownset is` does not adversely affect the kerning of the letter `i`.

The text version is also `\smash`ed to avoid affecting the line spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}
\newcommand\crownset[1]{\stackengine{.3pt}{#1}{\kern-.07em%
  \smash{\includegraphics[width=0.5em]%
  {queen-crown-clipart-black-and-white-black-crown-clipart-nTE8GkyTA}}}%
  {O}{c}{F}{T}{S}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\crownset A new d\crownset ay \crownset is dawning.
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A royal post ;-) (Actually, I would not use it, however :D)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Perhaps a royal flush, then?

Comment: Rather a fit of typographical pain (;-) -- not the solution itself, of course. Sadly, your solution is underrated. I just glued a few lines together and got of bunch of upvotes for basically nothing...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Regarding: "I just glued a few lines together", that is what they call "elegant"!

Comment: Wow, that is pretty!!

Comment: @Steven B. Segletes: Why are you using stackengine instead of the accents package?  Stackengine looks more impressive, but placement seems better with the accents package, e.g. with the letter $f$.  I used your crown with `\newcommand{\sscrown}[1]{\accentset{\includegraphics[width=1.2ex]{crown}}{#1}}
` which appears to work well.

Comment: @JPi There's an old expression, "if the only tool in your toolbox is a hammer, pretty soon every problem starts looking like a nail."  And since I wrote `stackengine`, you would not be the first to comment that it may figure over-prominently in my toolbox.

Comment: @JPi Of course, one can account for the letter slant with `stackengine`, as well, by modifying the horizontal kern as a function of the letter height, as my EDIT reveals.

Comment: @Steven B. Segletes: Ah great, thanks!  (it was curiosity, not criticism)

Comment: It would be better to use a vector graphic than a bitmap, though?

Answer (score 22):

A very primitive way, with `\symking` from `skak` package by Ulrike Fischer (symbolizing a 'crown') and `\overset` (Thanks to Ulrike Fischer following information: the fonts for `\symking` are provided by the `chessfss` package actually, which is loaded by `skak`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{skak}
\usepackage{accents}

\newcommand{\crown}[1]{\overset{\symking}{#1}}
\newcommand{\xcrown}[1]{\accentset{\symking}{#1}}

\begin{document}

$\crown{x}$
$\xcrown{x}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ingenious to think about the `skak` package!

Comment: @JPi: The only package that I remember that has something like a `crown`

Comment: Right: the reason I asked the question is that I couldn't.

Comment: @JPi: well, there might be others, basically any chess-related package should provide such symbols.

Comment: @http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/31729/christian-hupfer: Ok.  I'll accept it: works well once paired with `\accentset` from the accents package.

Comment: actually it is not skak that provides the symbol but chessfss (loaded by skak).

Comment: You could probably also use a queen instead of a king, if you want something more [Eastern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_crown) and less... [St. Edwardsy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St_Edward's_Crown).

Comment: @Kevin: A crown is a crown ;-) Thanks for suggestion